# Getting quick Server Ping Results in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written below PowerShell script to get the ping results of server and it also generates the log for the same. My script works fine, also generates log but it take so much time as there are many servers. Is there any way I can quickly get the results. I have tried start-job but that generates error.

```
   $logpath = $logpath +"\" +$Logname

    Function Log($txt)
    {
         if (! (Test-Path $logpath)) {
                New-Item $logpath |Out-Null
         }

         $date = Get-Date -Format "dd_MMM_yyyy_hh:mm:ss - "
         $txt1 = ($date + $txt)

         Add-Content "$logpath"  "$txt1"
         Add-Content "$logpath" " "
     }
     $ServerDetails=import-csv $Servercsv

     foreach($servertest in $ServerDetails)
     {
        if((Test-Connection -ComputerName $servertest.servers -Count 2))
        {
          Log("'" + $servertest.servers + "' Successfully started operation")
          Write-Host "Started Operation Successfully"
        }
        if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $servertest.servers -Count 2))
         {
           Log("'" + $servertest.servers + "'Servers are not pinging")
           Write-Host "Servers are not pinging"

         }
     }
```

Comment: You could save some time when you use `-Count 1` instead of `-Count 2`. And you should not run `Test-Connection` twice for the same server. Run it once and save it to a variable and work with the variable. ;-)

Comment: what errors did you get when you tried the Start-Job? If you have a small chunk of servers you want to go through, then asynchronous is probably the best bet.

Comment: I am getting "Access to the path  is denied." when I am executing my function within scriptblock in start-job. I want to generate logs in that path. If I don't use scriptblock then it works fine.

Comment: Asynchrously is indeed the best bet, for this you might use this [logging framework](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry) which is able to write/buffer from multiple instances, but is is better to wait in the main thread for each job to finish and do the logging from there.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your "log" function works as expected you could make the rest of your code a little more efficient:

```
$ServerList = import-csv $Servercsv

foreach ($ComputerName in $ServerList) {
    $Connection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName.servers -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($Connection) {
        Log("'" + $ComputerName.servers + "' Successfully started operation")
        Write-Host "Started Operation Successfully"
    }
    Else {
        Log("'" + $ComputerName.servers + "'Servers are not pinging")
        Write-Host "Servers are not pinging"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Test-Connection with an array of targetnames and the asjob parameter is fast (powershell 5.1).  Unresponsive addresses have a null responsetime.  Annoyingly, the property names don't match the column headings.

```
$list = 'microsoft.com','yahoo.com'
$results = test-connection $list -count 1 -asjob | receive-job -wait
$results | select address,responsetime


address       responsetime
-------       ------------
yahoo.com               39
microsoft.com
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess you need to elleborate on the required logging.